# stop / start / pause in matplotlib animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I'm using FuncAnimation in matplotlib's animation module for some basic animation. This function perpetually loops through the animation. Is there a way by which I can pause and restart the animation by, say, mouse clicks?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is [a FuncAnimation example](http://scipyscriptrepo.com/wp/?p=9) which I modified to pause on mouse clicks.
Since the animation is driven by a generator function, `simData`, when the global variable `pause` is True, yielding the same data makes the animation appear paused.

The value of `paused` is toggled by setting up an event callback:

```
def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

pause = False
def simData():
    t_max = 10.0
    dt = 0.05
    x = 0.0
    t = 0.0
    while t < t_max:
        if not pause:
            x = np.sin(np.pi*t)
            t = t + dt
        yield x, t

def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True

def simPoints(simData):
    x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    line.set_data(t, x)
    return line, time_text

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f s'
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=10,
    repeat=True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Cute, handy, entertaining, and in a way, nostalgic; https://youtu.be/TxmZ5sabk7U?t=17 or https://youtu.be/C1HuX6nQnQY?t=211

Comment: @unutbu It does not work for me. The window is closed quickly. My platform: Windows 10, python 3.8, matplotlib 3.4.2.

Answer (score 25):

This works...

```
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animfunc[,..other args])

#pause
anim.event_source.stop()

#unpause
anim.event_source.start()
```

Answer (score 17):

Combining both the answers from @fred and @unutbu here, we can add an onClick function after creating the animation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()

def run_animation():
    anim_running = True

    def onClick(event):
        nonlocal anim_running
        if anim_running:
            anim.event_source.stop()
            anim_running = False
        else:
            anim.event_source.start()
            anim_running = True

    def animFunc( ...args... ):
        # Animation update function here

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)

    anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animFunc[,...other args])

run_animation()
```

Now we can simply stop or start the animation with clicks.

Comment: What version of matplotlib are you running?  This doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @bretcj7 I'm using version 1.5.3. Sorry, should have mentioned that!

Comment: I can't seem to find the documentation on matplotlib for the event_source.stop() or start?  Does it exist?

Comment: You need to assign the function to the event also, `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)` and I guess replace `nonlocal` with `global`

Answer (score 12):

I landed on this page trying to implement the same functionality, pausing matplotlibs animation. The other answers are great, but in addition I wanted to be able to manually loop through the frames using the arrow keys. For anyone looking for the same functionality, here's my implementation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
txt = fig.text(0.5,0.5,'0')

def update_time():
    t = 0
    t_max = 10
    while t<t_max:
        t += anim.direction
        yield t

def update_plot(t):
    txt.set_text('%s'%t)
    return txt

def on_press(event):
    if event.key.isspace():
        if anim.running:
            anim.event_source.stop()
        else:
            anim.event_source.start()
        anim.running ^= True
    elif event.key == 'left':
        anim.direction = -1
    elif event.key == 'right':
        anim.direction = +1

    # Manually update the plot
    if event.key in ['left','right']:
        t = anim.frame_seq.next()
        update_plot(t)
        plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_press)
anim = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=update_time,
                         interval=1000, repeat=True)
anim.running = True
anim.direction = +1
plt.show()
```

Some notes:

- To be able to modify the values of `running` and `direction`, I assigned them to `anim`. It avoids using nonlocal (not avaible in Python2.7) or global (not desirable since I'm running this code within another function). Not sure whether this is good practice, but I found it quite elegant.
- For the manual update, I'm accessing `anim`'s generator object that FuncAnimation uses to update the plot. This ensures that when I resume the animation, it starts from the active frame rather than from where it was originally paused.

Comment: Where are `.running` and `.direction` documented? I'm wondering if `event_source.start()` is "less" undocumented feature.

Comment: `.running` and `.direction` are not documented, I made that up myself. See e.g. [this](http://blog.lerner.co.il/python-attributes/) blog post: you can just assign new attributes to any object and it will probably work just fine. Not sure whether this is good practice, but I found it quite useful here. I'm not sure whether `event_source.start()` is documented, but I think I found it in the source code or in another SO post.

Comment: As soon as i press left or right key I get following error: t = anim.frame_seq.next()
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: @Gino Gulamhussene
I bet you are using python3 :-)... change t = anim.frame_seq.next() to t = anim.frame_seq.__next__().

Comment: Very elegant! I just modified a bit the generator. As it was values of t could become negative... ok will do it later... lol edit queue look to be full thanks to a missclick!

Comment: How to make this work with blit=true (see my [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70145156/step-forward-and-backward-frame-by-frame-in-animation-in-matplolib-problem-when])

Answer (score 1):

Since there are quite a few comments on different answers asking for documented feature, I dug deeper based on [fred's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461388/7976805). It seems to work, but since matplotlib 3.4.0 there are new functions to pause and resume plotting: [`pause()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.pause) and [`resume()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.resume). They call `event_source.stop()` and `start()` internally, but they also pause animation altogether, which may reduce the hardware strain.

They can be called on any `matplotlib.animation.Animation` object, including `FuncAnimation` subclass.