# Python - Stop FuncAnimation

Tags: python, matplotlib

Does anyone know the preferred method for stopping FuncAnimation? I am using it to record data from a oscilloscope and would like to be able to pause and restart the data on demand. Is there any way I can send a button click event to it?

Thanks, Derek

Comment: do not think that functionality is currently implemented.  You are probably better off doing the timers your self in this case.

Comment: Got it. So would you suggest using the TimedAnimation function then as it takes an event source which I assume means it can be stopped? I would then set up my own timers in a separate function to update the data to the figure as you said.

Comment: No, don't use the `animation` module at all (except as reference).  There is (to my knowledge) no way to 'pause' running animations.

Comment: There is now the option to use the animation's event source, `anim.event_source.stop()` to stop the animation. See bottom two answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732379/stop-start-pause-in-python-matplotlib-animation).

Answer (score 6):

The `FuncAnimation` is a subclass of `TimedAnimation`. It takes frames as an input for update functionm, which could be a number or a generator. It takes `repeat` as an argument, which is inherited from `TimedAnimation`, by setting `reapeat` to `False` you could stop the animation to repeat itself.

PS: Matplotlib documentation is lame, mistakes, lazy writing style, unclear explanation. Sometime, I really have to dig into the source code to figure out what to do.

Like `FuncAnimation`, it also takes `fargs` as an extra arguments for `update` function, but in its documentation, it doesn't say the type of `fargs`. In fact, what I found in its source code, `fargs is used as a list`.

Answer (score 2):

There may be some modules but I define my own pause function. It freezes the animation by clicking somewhere on the figure. When you click again, it continues to plot the animation.

You have to define a flag before the begin of your animation. Inside your animation function (the function which will be called during you animation is plotted), you have to define a a control block like: `if not pause:` and then write your codes for plotting the function below.

You may have already checked, but [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732379/stop-start-pause-in-python-matplotlib-animation) gives an example of what I mean. I guess, many people do it in this way.

Notice that, the switch for pause is done with the following function:

```
def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True
```

And you have to further add this line somewhere before you call FuncAnimation

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
```