# How can i make points of a python plot appear over time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a animation where my data points would gradually appear on my graph and freeze when all the data points have appeared. I've seen in done with correlations i'm just not too sure how to do it with just individual points themselves

This isn't something that will show anything particularly useful but i though it would look cool since i am trying to visualize some location data on a map

I know this isn't very clear so please as for clarifications, I'm not too sure how to phrase my problem very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) is the right tool for you. First create an empty graph, and then gradually add data points to it in the function. The following piece of code will illustrate it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.random(10)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
graph, = plt.plot([], [], 'o')

def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(x[:i+1], y[:i+1])
    return graph

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=10, interval=200)
plt.show()
```

The result (saved as gif file) is shown below:
[image]

**EDIT:** To make the animation look stopped when finished in matplotlib window, you need to make it infinite (omit `frames` parameter in `FuncAnimation`), and set the frame counter to the last number in your frame series:

```
def animate(i):
    if i > 9:
        i = 9
    graph.set_data(x[:i+1], y[:i+1])
    return graph

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=200)
```

Or, which is better, you can set `repeat` parameter in `FuncAnimation` to `False`, as per answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21999711/python-stop-funcanimation) question.

**EDIT 2:** To animate a scatter plot, you need a whole bunch of other methods. A piece of code is worth a thousand words:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.random(10)
size = np.random.randint(150, size=10)
colors = np.random.choice(["r", "g", "b"], size=10)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
graph = plt.scatter([], [])

def animate(i):
    graph.set_offsets(np.vstack((x[:i+1], y[:i+1])).T)
    graph.set_sizes(size[:i+1])
    graph.set_facecolors(colors[:i+1])
    return graph

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, repeat=False, interval=200)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Also is there a way to set_data by individual points rather than lists?

Comment: First question: that depends on whether you want to show the graph in matplotlib window, or save it as a file and embed into a presentation. Yes, it is possible in matplotlib window - see edit for details. If you'd like to stop animated file instead - that's up to presentation software.

Comment: Second question: Why do you need that? If you have a bunch of individual points that you want to display, you always have the possibility to put them in a list.

Comment: can .i change the marker sizes and color of the points in .data_set?

Comment: i needed to do so and that is why i asked if i could .set data by individual points rather than lists.

Comment: Ok, then you need a scatter plot. Scatter plots (`PathCollections`) instead of `set_data` have `set_facecolors`, `set_sizes` and `set_offsets` methods. `set_offsets` takes 2d array as an argument (contrary to `set_data`). See another edit.

Comment: Thanks that covers about everything

Comment: actually 2 small things, for the 'i' in animate(i), its that the frame number? and what is the purpose of the '.T ' in .graph_offset?

Comment: `i` is the frame number, and `.T ` stands for transposing test data, as `graph.set_offsets` expects as input 2D array with eath row representing one point.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers, it would took me so much time to try to do this with just with whats out there.

Comment: Can you please share how to set the color using a color map based on a third variable for the scatter plot?