# How to continously plot the multipication of two matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have two matrics, A and X:

```
  |2 -1| = A       and       |x| = X
  |-1 2|                     |y|
```

Now, I want to plot all the resulting plots as a matplotlib plot. For example something similar to this loop:

```py
for x in range(1,100)
     for y in in range(1,100)
```

But, what I specifically like is an animation. So, I can see as each point is being plotted. Sp first the `X` matrix will be `1,1` then `1,2` all the way to `100,100`. If the question is not clear, please ask for a clarification.

Comment: A good example for animating the plots is here: https://towardsdatascience.com/animations-with-matplotlib-d96375c5442c

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275189/how-can-i-make-points-of-a-python-plot-appear-over-time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i make points of a python plot appear over time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275189/how-can-i-make-points-of-a-python-plot-appear-over-time)