# Change point color in python plot animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, colors

I have a list of points, lets say as (x,y) pairs. I am trying to animate a plot so that each frame of the animation, a new point show up on the plot in a different color. Specifically on the 0th frame, the 0th point appears, on the the 1st frame, the 1st point appears, and so on. I would also like to have these points appear in a new color, specifically like a linear progression through a color palette as the points progress, so that you can "follow" the points by their color. This is similar to, and how I got as far as I am now: [How can i make points of a python plot appear over time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33275189/how-can-i-make-points-of-a-python-plot-appear-over-time). The first animation in the link is spot on, except without the points changing colors.

I am using `matplotlib`, `matplotlib.pyplot`, and `FuncAnimation` from `matplotlib.animation`
What I have already:

```
    def plot_points_over_time(list_of_points):
        num_points = len(list_of_points)
        fig = plt.figure()
        x, y = zip(*list_of_points)
        plt.xlim(min(x),max(x))
        plt.ylim(min(y),max(y))
        colors = [plt.cm.gist_rainbow(each) for each in np.linspace(0,1,num_points)]
        graph, = plt.plot([],[],'o')
        def animate(i):
            graph.set_data(x[:i+1],y[:i+1])
            return graph
        ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = num_points, repeat = False, interval = 60000/num_points)
        plt.show()
```

I can change the color of all of the points together on each frame by including the line `graph.set_color(colors[i])` in the `animate` function, but not each point individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with some digging and trial and error:

```
def plot_points_over_time(list_of_points):
    num_points = len(list_of_points)
    fig = plt.figure()
    x, y = zip(*list_of_points)
    plt.xlim(min(x),max(x))
    plt.ylim(min(y),max(y))
    colors = [plt.cm.gist_rainbow(each) for each in np.linspace(0,1,num_points)]
    scat, = plt.plot([],[])
    def animate(i):
        scat.set_offsets(np.c_[x[:i+1], y[:i+1]])
        scat.set_color(colors[:i+1])
        return scat,
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = num_points, repeat = False, interval = 60000/num_points)
    plt.show()
```