# Having trouble pausing animation with code based on example

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, event-handling

I want to animate some data, and I have been following the example from another stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732379/stop-start-pause-in-python-matplotlib-animation) to enable pausing. However, I am doing something a little different. In that example, they are using the sine function which can take non-integer values in the argument. What I am doing is plotting a set of data in the y-axis and matching it with a corresponding x-value (time in this case).

---

### Desired Output

I simply want the output to plot the data and update the tick marks as it goes (thus the `ax.set_xlim(0, i/sf)` below), while being able to pause or play the animation.

---

### Close but not correct solution

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as am

length = 8e6
data = np.random.rand(length)
sf = 100 #Sampling frequency in MHz
x = np.arange(length)/sf

pause = False

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    if not pause:
        y = data[0:i]
        xax = x[0:i]
        line.set_data(xax, y)
        ax.set_xlim(0, i/sf)
        time_text.set_text(time_template%(i/sf))
        return line, time_text

def onPress(event):
    if event.key==' ':
        global pause
        pause ^= True 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(min(data),max(data))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f $\mu$s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
anim = am.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=40, init_func=init)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPress)

plt.show()
```

The problem with this solution is that when I pause and then unpause the animation the plot draws data to whatever it would have been at that point in time, had I not paused it.

You should be able to copy and paste this code to reproduce on your own machine.

---

### Also Tried

I tried a similar structure to that of the example I linked. It doesn't work either.

The problem is nothing seemingly happens when I run the program. I think it's plotting something, because I can see the plot when I try to move around the plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as am

length = 8e6
data = np.random.rand(length)
sf = 100 #Sampling frequency in MHz
x = np.arange(length)/sf 

pause = False

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def theData():
    i=0
    while i<50:
         if not pause:
            y = data[0:i]
            t = x[0:i]
            i=i+1
            yield t, y, i

def animate(theData):
    t = theData[0]
    y = theData[1]
    i = theData[2]
    line.set_data(t, y)
    ax.set_xlim(0, i/sf)
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    return line, time_text

def onPress(event):
    if event.key==' ':
        global pause
        pause ^= True 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(min(data),max(data))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f $\mu$s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
anim = am.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, theData, interval=40, init_func=init)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPress)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument passed to `animate` is a frame number. However, this number increments whether or not the animation is paused.

So instead, introduce your own global variable, `frame`, which records the true frame number and which only increments when the animation is not paused:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as am

length = 8*10**6
data = np.random.rand(length)
sf = 100 #Sampling frequency in MHz
x = np.arange(length)/sf

pause = False
frame = 0

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    global frame
    if not pause:
        frame += 1
        y = data[0:frame]
        xax = x[0:frame]
        line.set_data(xax, y)
        ax.set_xlim(0, frame/sf)
        time_text.set_text(time_template%(frame/sf))
        return line, time_text

def onPress(event):
    if event.key==' ':
        global pause
        pause ^= True 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15)) 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(min(data),max(data))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f $\mu$s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
anim = am.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=40, init_func=init)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', onPress)

plt.show()
```