# Python Matplotlib FuncAnimation.save() only saves 100 frames

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am trying to save an animation I've created with the FuncAnimation class in Matplotlib. My animation is more complicated, but I get the same error when I try to save the simple example given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732379/stop-start-pause-in-python-matplotlib-animation).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.animation as animation

pause = False
def simData():
    t_max = 10.0
    dt = 0.05
    x = 0.0
    t = 0.0
    while t < t_max:
        if not pause:
            x = np.sin(np.pi*t)
            t = t + dt
        yield x, t

def onClick(event):
    global pause
    pause ^= True

def simPoints(simData):
    x, t = simData[0], simData[1]
    time_text.set_text(time_template%(t))
    line.set_data(t, x)
    return line, time_text

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=10) # I'm still not clear on this stucture...
ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)

time_template = 'Time = %.1f s'    # prints running simulation time
time_text = ax.text(0.05, 0.9, '', transform=ax.transAxes)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onClick)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=10,
    repeat=True)
plt.show()
```

However, when I try to save this animation by adding the line

```
ani.save('test.mp4')
```

at the end, only the first 100 frames are saved.

After the animation is saved, the function restarts and displays as expected, displaying and updating the figure 200 times (or until t reaches t_max, whatever I set that to be). But the movie that is saved only contains the first 100 frames.

The pause functionality makes it tricky. Without it I could just put in frames = 200 into the FuncAnimation call rather that using the iterator/generator type function I currently have for the frames argument. But by just putting in frames = 200, the frame count seems to be un-pauseable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If pausing like this works interactively, and without pausing you can save all the frames you want, is there really an issue? Or did I misunderstand your situation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit=False, interval=10,
                              repeat=True, save_count=200)
```

will solve the ploblem.

Internally, `save` only saves a fixed number of frames.  If you pass in a fixed length sequence or a number, mpl can correctly guess the length.  If you pass in a (possibly infinite) generator and do not pass in `save_count` it defaults to 100.

Comment: I am doing a very similar with the pause and start on the animation and by default it starts paused.  When i put the save method after the FuncAnimation call and start the plotting it doesn't seem to render anything or save the frames.  I was using imagemagick, also i am using a generator for plotting the data so i won't have a save_count.

Comment: You can use `save_count=sys.maxsize` if you don't know the size ahead of time, at least for `.mp4` export

Comment: thanks @StanleyBak the `sys.maxsize` solved the problem. But while constantly saving the plot to a mp4 file, the inline graph stopped updating its animation. Do we have a fix for it?