# Pause matplotlib custom animation loop without polling

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have an animation that I can play and pause as desired. As shown in the code below, my method for pausing the animation is to intermittently poll the `paused` global state variable.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

paused = False

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)
ax.set_xlim(-10, 10)
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

plt.ion()
plt.show()

def pause_anim(event):
    global paused
    paused = not paused

pause_ax = fig.add_axes((0.7, 0.03, 0.1, 0.04))
pause_button = Button(pause_ax, 'pause', hovercolor='0.975')
pause_button.on_clicked(pause_anim)

x = np.arange(-50, 51)

line = ax.plot([], [], [], c="r")[0]


for y in np.arange(1, 30, 3):
    z = - x**2 + y - 100

    line.set_data(x, 0)
    line.set_3d_properties(z)

    plt.draw()
    plt.pause(0.2)

    while paused:
        plt.pause(0.5)
```

Is there some way to pause the animation without polling and instead use some sort of interrupt driven method?

Comment: As said in the [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43385128/4124317), `FuncAnimation` has the methods `.event_source.stop()` and `.event_source.start()`. Since  `FuncAnimation` would anyways allow for much cleaner solutions, I wonder why you don't want to use it. Could it be that the problem you are trying to solve in reality is a completely different one?

Comment: The cost of refactoring my code to use `FuncAnimation` is significant, so that's why I'm doing the animation part manually. In another way, I'm also trying to get a better understanding of Matplotlib's internals. Don't feel obliged to answer this question, I'm still considering whether to delete it or not.