# Step forward and backward frame by frame in animation in matplolib: Problem when using blit=True

Tags: python, matplotlib

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49382421/406686) shows an approach to implement pause and stepping frame by frame in matplotlib. However in my case I want to use blitting for performance reasons. But in this case the example doesn't work

1. Run `python3 animation.py` it does display an empty canvas and says (in the console) `TypeError 'Text' object is not iterable`
2. If I hit the right button, it shows 1. Then I can go through the numbers using left/right buttons.
3. Using space to start or stop the animation doesn't have any effect.

If I remove `blit=True` everything works as expected.

So how to change the example to make it work with blitting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as ani

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
txt = fig.text(0.5,0.5,'0',fontsize=30)

def update_time():
    t = 0
    while True:
        t += anim.direction
        yield t

def update_plot(t):
    txt.set_text('%s'%t)
    return txt

def on_press(event):
    if event.key.isspace():
        if anim.running:
            anim.event_source.stop()
        else:
            anim.event_source.start()
        anim.running ^= True
    elif event.key == 'left':
        anim.direction = -1
    elif event.key == 'right':
        anim.direction = +1

    # Manually update the plot
    if event.key in ['left','right']:
        t = anim.frame_seq.__next__()
        update_plot(t)
        plt.draw()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_press)
anim = ani.FuncAnimation(fig, update_plot, frames=update_time,interval=100,blit=True)
anim.running = True
anim.direction = +1
plt.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: I'm not sure - does blotting even work with figure objects?  Did you try putting the text in the axes instead?